# Firebase Event missing Parameters in Android

Tags: java, android, events, firebase-analytics

we are using the Firebase Analytics. Where we posting some custom events and detailed parameters.
Those parameters are available during Debug view i.e we can see the values and keys
But not on the events screen.

Below the screen shot
https://prnt.sc/vi1ruo

Thanks